# How to use one print line to fill 2 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays, input, 2d

I am trying to use one print line from the user input to fill two separate 3x3 arrays, but I seem to be only able to do two 2 print lines of input, 1 for each array set. How would I cut out the need for two separate scan lines and just have the user put in all 18 integers and placed in each cell respectively? 
This is the two separate prompts for the user:

```
int m1 [][] = new int[3][3];
int m2 [][] = new int[3][3];      
System.out.print("Enter List1: ");
for (int row = 0; row < m1.length; row++)
{
   for(int column = 0; column < m1[row].length; column++)
   {
      m1[row][column] = input.nextInt();
   }
 }

System.out.print("Enter List2: ");
for (int row = 0; row < m2.length; row++)
{
   for(int column = 0; column < m2[row].length; column++)
   {
      m2[row][column] = input.nextInt();
   }
 }
```

Here we have two prompts for user input each filling the array separately. Could this be cut down to one prompt and fill the first 9 numbers to the first array and the last 9 to the second array?

Comment: Yes it could be cut down that way. How have you tried to do that? Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper Yes I have tried, my problem is that when i try to combine them I get an out of bounds exception because it try to put the full input in one array. I need it done this way because Im attempting to make the array do several tasks at once after the numbers are typed in as fast as possible.

Comment: Remove `System.out.print("Enter List2: ");` and there will be only one print line left in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove `System.out.print("Enter List2: ");`, then users can enter 18 numbers without interruption.

```
int m1 [][] = new int[3][3];
int m2 [][] = new int[3][3];
System.out.print("Enter List1 and List2 (18 numbers): ");
for (int row = 0; row < m1.length; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < m1[row].length; column++)
    {
        m1[row][column] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
for (int row = 0; row < m2.length; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < m2[row].length; column++)
    {
        m2[row][column] = input.nextInt();
    }
}

//Print two array
System.out.print("List1: ");
for (int row = 0; row < m1.length; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < m1[row].length; column++)
    {
        System.out.print(m1[row][column] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
//Print two array
System.out.print("List2: ");

for (int row = 0; row < m2.length; row++)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < m2[row].length; column++)
    {
        System.out.print(m2[row][column] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The input & output when executing above program:

```
Enter List1 and List2 (18 numbers): 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
List1: 
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 
List2: 
10 11 12 
13 14 15 
16 17 18
```